# In ICS is it possible to set the "Restrict background data" setting from code (programmatically)?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In ICS there is now the "Restrict background data" setting in the Network -> Data usage settings screens.

Is there a way to programmatically set "Restrict background data" for my application?

OR

Is there a way to bring up the "Data usage" settings that has the option for my application?

Comment: I think this will be somewhat helpful to you, although possibly not enough to answer your question: http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.html#NetworkUsage

Comment: The developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.html#NetworkUsage  is only about replacing the generic data usage screen with an app specific one.   What I want is to bring up the generic one that lets the user access the Android's built in restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

You can start from the Overview of [Data Usage](http://source.android.com/tech/datausage/kernel-overview.html) Android Tech Info page.

Each network device driver will report its usage statsitics to `xt_qtaguid` module in the android-3.0 Linux kernel. Then, from the framework you can specify additional rules to restrict background data traffic for an application.

Try providing `counterSet` and `UID` params to `com.android.server.NetworkManagementSocketTagger` `setKernelCounterSet()` method. Where `counterSet` values are defined in `android.net.NetworkPolicyManager` and `UID` would be your application id obtained through `ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo().uid`.

I hope this gets you started.

Comment: I've tried implementing this on a non-rooted device through reflection, as `NetworkManagementSocketTagger` is not exposed through the SDK. `setKernelCounterSet()` executes, but I see in Logcat: `I/qtaguid(25017): Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10183) res=-1 errno=1` and `W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(25017): setKernelCountSet(10183, 0) failed with errno -1`. I haven't tested on a rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second option, you may look into this intent

[ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE)

"Activity Action: Show settings for managing network data usage of a specific application."

Comment: ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE brings up a menu that lists applications with that action in their intent filters.

Comment: This is so that the Android settings app (data usage specifically) can launch an activity of your app that monitors data usage.